# cannot find name 'angular'

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

This code is angularjs 1.4x with ionic 3. I want to Implement this code some changes in angular 7 with ionic 4.I am getting error like this "cannot find name 'angular'". Please help me.

`var vector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app=vectorApp]')).scope().$root;`

Comment: Can you run `npm install`?

Comment: Not working npm install @Fearcoder

Comment: In Angular 7 (Angular 2+) you can not use `angular.element`

Comment: Ok, I will remove It. "var vector = document.querySelector('[ng-app=vectorApp]');" this is correct or not

Comment: declare var angular: any;  -- try this

Comment: Though it's possible to use `document.querySelector`, it is not the _Angular way_. 
One of the main goals of Angular is to stop you from having to access the DOM directly.
I'd recommend using Angulars `@ViewChild` annotation to retrieve an HTML element.
https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: yes, It's solved the error now getting new error. my code is: "if (this.pluginName[1] == "getDeviceModelAndOSVersion")". error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined.    @user9088454

Comment: Angular 1 and Angular 2+ have absolutely nothing in common. You need to rewrite the application from scratch, nothing is going to work otherwise. Besides, `document.querySelector` has nothing to do in an Angular app.

Answer (score 0):

Do not keep old codebase continuously you have to migrate some how someday so start it by now or you will face many issues keeping old codebase so my suggestion is migrate to `Angular 2+`

> https://wtcindia.wordpress.com/2016/09/23/top-5-reasons-why-one-must-migrate-to-angular-2/

Comment: The mobile app developed Angularjs 1.4. The plugin also developed Angularjs 1.4. the plugin part of code used in angularjs app. Now I am newly developed angular 7 code. I want to convert plugin part code into angular 7. the code is below:  var vector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app=vectorApp]')).scope().$root;

Comment: What is the plugin

Comment: This is customized plugin to access server. here is full code: "if (pluginName == 'getDeviceModelAndOSVersion') {
          
          
          var vectorAppRootScope = angular.element(document.querySelector('[app-root]')).scope().$root;
         
  
          browser.executeScript({
            code: successFunctionName + '("' + vectorAppRootScope.this.device.model + '","' + vectorAppRootScope.this.device.version + '");'
            
          });
        }"@ORBIT

Comment: it can be get in new IONIC versions

Comment: It is possible to change ionic 4 version with angular 7. Please help @ORBIT

Comment: do you want to get device model and device version?

Comment: I want change below this code to angular 7: ```var vector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app=vectorApp]')).scope().$root;``` Please help@ORBIT